# Can I reduce voltage of an led?

Tags: voltage, led

I'm still new to electronics, so beae with me. Luckily it's a short question:
I'm following a schematic that calls for a 1.7-1.8v led, but unfortunately I only have 3v 20mA LEDs.. Is there any way I can reduce the voltage, like with a resistor or something? I tried looking it up but all I found was reducing current from a battery with a resistor.

Here is my schematic, it's an led light indicator.
[image]

Comment: Post your schematic (ctrl+m opens the editor). With it, we can help you more.

Comment: I couldn't resist.. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/is-it-bear-or-bare-with-me

Comment: Can you clarify that schematic? What is Vin?

Comment: Yes you can run it off as low a voltage as you want. It just won't light up...

Comment: @BrianDrummond The LED will light if the voltage is 4.9V or **below** (see my answer for circuit analysis). I think it's supposed to be a low voltage indicator for a 5V line.

Answer (score 4):

LEDs like all diodes have a voltage characteristic that is defined mostly by the materials used to make up the junction. This is referred to as the forward bias voltage often notated as Vf. You can vary this voltage a little by controlling the current you feed the LED but for the most part diodes like to set their own voltage when fed a current within their recommended operating range. Feed the LED less current and you will operate it at a slightly lower voltage.

Some quick points:

- Less current = less brightness and lower voltage (too little and it won't turn on at all)
- More current = more brightness and higher voltage (too much and it will pop)
- Look at the datasheet for a given LED and find the graph where it shows it's current to voltage relationship.
- Put a resistor in series with your LED (more resistance = less current and voltage)
- White LEDs require the highest Vf to operate followed by blue followed by blue green. Red and yellow LEDs can operate at lower voltages.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't just "reduce the voltage of a LED".  LED forward voltage is directly tied to the color of light it produces.  White LEDs, which are really blue or near ultra-violet with phosphors to re-emit different colors, require over 3 V.

Instead of reducing the voltage required by a 3 V LED, you could possibly change the circuit to provide the 3 V instead of the 1.8 V it does now.  How easy or not that is depends greatly on the existing circuit.

Of course the simple answer is to get a 1.8 V LED.  Those are cheap and abundant, and can be easily obtained from the other end of the internet.

Answer (score 2):

No, but if you post your schematic there is a very good chance we can help you make it work with you 3V LED's (EDIT: see below).

LED's are not resistive loads, with the current and voltage scaling according to V = IR. Rather, they are all or nothing: they drop the voltage by whatever they are rated for at whatever current you put through them.

Look at this chart for diode conductivity (1/Resistance) (from http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e84/lectures/figures/diode1.gif ):
[image: diode drop]
Look at the left image. This image is for a diode with a voltage drop of ~0.6V.

You see that the LED will not conduct *at all* below its rated voltage (0.6V in this image, 3V in your case). Above that, it will conduct all the current you put through it (more or less, there is a small region where its conductivity increases exponentially).

This is not a good situation. Our two options are not on at all or exploded due to over current. That is why the resistor is used: to limit the current. Consider this schematic with a 5V source, a 3V LED, and a 100 ohm resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKHYvr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LED will conduct at over 3V, so therefore node A will be at 3V. Therefore, the voltage drop across the resistor is going to be 5V - 3V = 2V. The current is given by V = IR: 2V/100 ohms = 20mA. The resistor limits the current to protect the LED.

EDIT: **CIRCUIT ANALYSIS**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW0y9j.png)</sup>

Due to the Zener diode D3, node 1 will always be at 3.3V. Due to Zener diode D1, node 2 will always be at Vin - 3.3V when the LED is off. The LED is supposed to turn on when V[node 1] is 1.7V (its voltage drop) higher than V[node 2]. Solving, that lets us know that the LED will turn on when Vin is less than 2x zener voltage drop - LED voltage drop, 2x3.3V - 1.7V = 4.9V as designed. With your 3V LEDs, that's 2x3.3V - 3V = 3.6V. Not good.

I see two options. One is to get 3.9V zeners, as then 2x3.9V - 3V = 4.8V. The other, probably cheaper one, is to get red LED's (all red LED's have voltage drops of about 1.7V).

**Conclusion:** Not easy to make it work with 3V LED's. Get a bunch of red LED's. You will use them in other projects and they cost almost nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I found it helpful! As requested, I've updated the original post with my schematic. Hope you (or anyone else) can help.